Paginate results from LDAP template search using ldapquery builder in spring boot
I want to paginate results of a LDAP template search like 20 results at a time, since I have a lot of users in our ldap. Here is my API method
@GetMapping("/v8/searchWithDate")
public ResponseEntity<String> userSearchWithDateFilter
        (@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers, @RequestParam("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date startDate, @RequestParam("endDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date endDate, @RequestParam("managerStatus") String managerStatus,  @RequestParam("accountStatus") String accountStatus)
        throws JsonProcessingException {

    List<SearchResponse> usersPropsList = null;
    String json = null;

    String beginDate;
    String finalDate;
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS'Z'");;

    beginDate = formatter.format(startDate);
    finalDate = formatter.format(endDate);



    usersPropsList = ldapClient.searchUserWithDate(null, beginDate, finalDate, managerStatus, accountStatus);

    int count = usersPropsList.size();
    json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(usersPropsList);

    if (json == null || json.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>( "{ \"error\": {\"message\": \" Not Found \",\"content\" :"  + json + " }}", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    // return new ResponseEntity<>( "{ \"data\": " + json + " }", HttpStatus.OK);
    return new ResponseEntity<>( "{ \"data\": " + json + ", \"count\": " + count + " }", HttpStatus.OK);

}

Here is my function
    public List<SearchResponse> searchUserWithDate(String attribPattern, String startDate, String endDate, String managerStatus, String accountStatus) {

    if (attribPattern == null) {
        attribPattern = "+"; //else: "memberOf"
    }


    if (Objects.equals(accountStatus, "1")) {
        accountStatus = "FALSE";
    } else {
        accountStatus = "TRUE";
    }

    List<SearchResponse> finalList = new ArrayList<>() ;

    try {
        String baseDN = buildDNbyCN().get("ldapAccountDN").toString();
        // (baseDN == null) ? "" : baseDN
        List<Map<String,String>> foundObj = ldapTemplate.search(
                LdapQueryBuilder.query().base((baseDN == null) ? "" : baseDN).attributes("*",attribPattern.toString()).where("objectclass").like("*")
                        .and(LdapQueryBuilder.query()
                                .where("createTimestamp").gte(startDate)
                                .and("createTimestamp").lte(endDate)
                                .and("pwdLockout").is(accountStatus)
                                .and("employeeType").is(managerStatus))
                        ,
                (AttributesMapper<Map<String,String>>) attrs
                        -> {
                    SearchResponse searchResponse = getObjectAttrs(attrs);
                    Map<String,String> ss = new HashMap<>();
                    // NOTE: If UID is not present it will be assigned with APPUID value (assuming appuid is not null)
                    String uid = "", appuid="";
                    if (attrs.get("appuid") != null) {
                        appuid = attrs.get("appuid").get().toString();
                    } else {
                        appuid = "";
                    }
                    if (attrs.get("uid") != null) {
                        uid = attrs.get("uid").get().toString();
                    }

                    if (uid != null && uid != "") {
                        finalList.add(searchResponse);
                    }
                    ss = searchResponse.getProperties();
                    return ss;


                }
        );
    } catch (Exception allExc) {
        LOG.error("=> (Error <searchUserV6>)" + allExc.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(allExc);
    }

    return finalList;
}

How can I paginate my results, I have tried the solution given here Return ldap entries on paginated form in springboot but I could not make it work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55420113/175554 may help
